# Git equivalent of Mercurial "hg commit -A -m <message>"

Tags: git, macos, mercurial

Recently I heard the news about BitBucket ending support for Mercurial so I'm making the switch to Git. It's just a one person repository that I basically use to back up my project and to have as a resource for old code (I don't do anything tricky at all). So I've gotten by all these years by simply using `hg commit -A -m <message>` to commit the entire project whenever I've made a significant amount of changes.

Now that I've made the switch to Git, I was wondering if someone could tell me the equivalent command to accomplish the same? I know there's `git commit -a -m <message>` but this gives me an odd message "nothing added to commit but untracked files present" which leaves me a little uncertain.

So I wanted to ask here, what command / commands would accomplish the same as the Mercurial command `hg commit -A -m <message>` ?

Comment: Note that the `-A` option to `hg commit` implies that Mercurial should run `hg addremove` before running `hg commit`. Git does not have any equivalent flag; `git commit -a` tells Git to run `git add -u` before the commit takes place, and `-u` is not the same as `hg addremove`. Since Git 2.0 you can run `git add -A; git commit`, and/or you can make an alias that does this. The `-A` option to `git add` *is* roughly equivalent to `hg addremove` (though there are important technical differences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning message you're seeing ("nothing added to commit but untracked files present") indicates that your files are untracked.

You must alert git to track changes to these files; accomplished using the `git add <filename>`.
To track all files, use the `git add *` wildcard file specifier.

From this point onwards, subsequent changes can be staged and committed using your specified command (`git commit -a -m <message>`).

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I need to do this everytime a file is added? Or will this automatically track any new file that gets created and eliminate anyone that gets removed?

Comment: you can also just write `git commit -am "some msg"` which is a but shorter.

Comment: This will track all files that are not tracked at the time of execution. New files will need to be marked as tracked after creation.